# Geting Certificate exception on .Net when accept the Fiddler certificate

Tags: .net, ssl-certificate, fiddler

In my local project when ı'm trying to send post request to outsource api, I want to watch my request and content of it (header, body ect.). I turn on HTTPS decryption and trust Fiddler's root certificate. But ı get that exception in my .Net project (work in docker container):

InnerException = {System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exceptio...

Any solution advice ? ty.

Comment: If you are in a docker container you need to trust the Fiddler root in that container also.

Comment: @Charlieface run the program in IIS Express, and got the solution. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program in IIS Express, not in Docker, and got the solution. Thanks for help.